# Simplify Linq Statement

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-objects

I have written the following linq statement but I can't help feeling it could be simplified somehow. The purpose is to take a `List<IEnumberable<Counterparty>>` (counterpartyStatic in the query) objects and find the Orders that have a ClientId equal to Counterparty.CounterpartyId. Those order should then have the field ClientDesc updated to match the Counterparty.DescriptionField. Once this is done I need to raise an event passing all the orders that have been updated.

The OrderCache is a dictionary in case that is not obvious.

Here is the existing code:

```
var updates = new List<Order>();
        lock (CacheLock)
        {
            counterpartyStatic.ToList().ForEach(cachedList =>
                cachedList.ToList().ForEach(
                    counterparty =>
                    {
                        var orders = OrderCache.Where(kvp => kvp.Value.Client == counterparty.CounterpartyId);
                        orders.ToList().ForEach(kvp =>
                        {
                            kvp.Value.ClientDesc = counterparty.Description;
                            updates.Add(kvp.Value);
                        });
                    }));
        }

        RaiseEvent(updates);
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that your "query" is really intended to cause side effects (ie: you're changing the value's ClientDesc in a deep nested loop), I would suggest writing this using loops instead of trying to use LINQ.  This has a couple of advantages - you're not making lists just to use `List<T>.ForEach`, and the intention is far more clear:

```
var updates = new List<Order>();

lock (CacheLock)
{
    foreach(var cachedList in counterpartyStatic)
    {
        foreach(var counterparty in cachedList)
        {
             var orders = OrderCache.Where(kvp => kvp.Value.Client == counterparty.CounterpartyId);
             foreach(var kvp in orders)
             {
                  kvp.Value.ClientDesc = counterparty.Description;
                  updates.Add(kvp.Value);
             }
         }
    }

    RaiseEvent(updates);
}
```

This is just as short as your original, but far more clear in terms of what is happening.

For an argument on why avoiding `List<T>.ForEach` can be beneficial, see [Eric Lippert's "foreach" vs "ForEach"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx).  `List<T>.ForEach` has even been removed for the new Windows Store apps, given the issues surrounding it.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. On reflection I'm inclined to agree that linq is perhaps making it less clear here. Good link to Erics blog, I hadn't seen that article before.

Answer (score 4):

(I'd written a long answer to this, but then my laptop crashed. Grrr.)

I would write a LINQ query to find all the values you're interested in, and then perform the mutation separately. So:

```
var query = from cachedList in counterpartyStatic
            from counterparty in cachedList
            join order in OrderCache.Values // Your query never uses the key
              on counterparty.CounterpartyId equals order.Client
            select new { Order = order, counterparty.Description };

var list = query.ToList(); // Avoid joining more than once

// Now do the update
foreach (var entry in list)
{
    entry.Order.ClientDesc = entry.Description;
}

// Now raise the events
RaiseEvents(list => list.Select(entry => entry.Order)); // Add ToList if needed
```

Comment: Regarding the anonymous type, I'd be tempted to write `new { order, counterParty.Description }` allowing the compiler to lift the property names from the expressions. Both expressions being valid c#, I'm curious to hear your thoughts.

Comment: @devgeezer: I *typically* try to stick to upper-cased property names, hence the `Order = order` - but absolutely for the description bit, and I'll fix that now :)

Comment: Thanks for the rationale. In the foreach loop, I think the assignment needs to be: entry.Order.ClientDesc = entry.Description; :)

Comment: @devgeezer: Yes indeed. Fixed.

Comment: Great answer Jon. I think you are absolutely right to separate the operation into a select and then mutate. I also agree with @Reed, in many ways Linq is perhaps making something more verbose and complex than it needs to be here. Would be interested to hear your thoughts on his approach.

Comment: IMHO, it is this separation that makes this LINQ approach favorable to the loop-based approach. LINQ forces updates to be split from the query (i.e. LINQ forces CQRS.) The loop approach interleaves the query and updates together. Future maintenance is made easier since it's harder to slip a side-effect into the LINQ query. The loops require more effort to read - try to determine not only whether there are side-effects but also whether the loops are just searching/filtering. Also, the `join` introduced will outperform `OrderCache.Where` since it employs hashing. Nice question/Nice answer

Comment: @user630190: What devgeezer said, basically :)